# Adding app widget from my app

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget

I have written an app which has main activity and app widget.
Dragging the widget to the home screen creates new widgets, as it should. I am looking for the way to do it when the user presses a button in the app activity.

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible... Example app that does this?

Comment: The contacts apps put contact shortcuts on the home screen by demand. Maybe this is not app widget? Maybe that is indeed something else which is a shortcut which gets specific contact parameters?
I do not need my widget to get updated periodically, so maybe the answer is there.

Comment: @Doron have you found any way to add widget programicaly?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to put widget on the "Home" screen programicaly.